# Getting Error "Maximum number of headers in one message should be less than or equal to 5" Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, postmessage

I am creating a draft message in office 365 using graph api and getting the following error

"error": {
"code": "InvalidInternetMessageHeaderCollection",
"message": "Maximum number of headers in one message should be less than or equal to 5."
}

I am using JSON instead of MIME because I need to add some extended properties before creating draft. Is there any way to merge email headers or anything else to overcome with this issue.

Note: I have emails with multiple email header to be created to o365 and want to keep all headers.